# GravityZone VA and AD Domains

Tags: login, domain, bitdefender

I just try to bring a BitDefender GravityZone VA back to life.

Question first, story below: **Is there any way I can change the AD domain of the GravityZone VA or add new web frontend users when there is no user left with access to the web frontend?**

The whole story:

- Weeks after a certain (dis)organization migrated from one AD domain to the other, someone found that BitDefender stopped updating.
- Some guy tracked down the issue, found the GravityZone VA and "remembered" its console password.
- The console application had the wrong AD domain given, so he changed it to the new one.

So far no harm done, but no change to the better either. So he headed for the web interface:

- He has no access to the web interface, in which only three AD accounts are enabled.
- A colleague, one of those magic three, logged into the web interface with his old AD login.
- He found another option "Active Directory" there, which still contained the old domain. Now he made a "minor" mistake: *He changed the domain to the new one.*
- A few seconds later, while trying to create a user login for his new AD user, his session timed out.
- Login with the credentials of either domain is not possible, because the GravityZone can neither find his new credentials in the authorized user list, nor his old credentials in the new LDAP.
- Changing the directory settings in the console back to the old one does not help either - they have no effect at all, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to login as bdadmin which is a linux account and also has root access to the webgui. Don't know the password? Just use passwd command on it through the console. If all else fails please contact there support.